# Why does a pre-pidded installation of Microsoft Expression Studio 3 ask for a key?

Tags: msdn, microsoft-expression, pre-pidded

I've downloaded Microsoft Expression Studio 3 from MSDN and installed it. However, after installation, I start the app and it asks for a valid product key, despite the fact that it's pre-pidded (e.g. requires no keys, or so the MSDN download page says).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the the trial and then try to install the MSDN version "over the top" of it? If so that won't work (I speak from experience). You have to uninstall the trial version and then install the MSDN version. I know that works.

Comment: No, I installed the MSDN version, since that is the one I downloaded.  I did have an install of the Expression Studio 2 trial version before that.

Comment: @AngryHacker - I wouldn't have thought having V2 installed would matter, but it might be worth uninstalling that first.

Comment: I did uninstall it prior to V3 installation.

Comment: @AngryHacker - then I'm all out of ideas, sorry.